# If the minus of two periodic function tends to zero can prove they are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, periodic-functions

Assume $f$ and $g$ are two periodic functions, and $f(x)-g(x)$ tends to zero when $x$ tends to infinity. The question is whether $f(x)=g(x)$ for all real number?

It is obviously true when $f$ and $g$ are continuous function, or the division of their period is rational number. However, I can’t see whether it’s true in all situations.

Comment: @Clarinetist  In truth, I can't follow the proof given in that question.  I don't know what "independent of $T_1$" means in that context.

Comment: @lulu I had the same reaction, see the answer I just added there.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Ah, thanks.  (+1)

Comment: You should specify whether you are assuming they are periodic with the same period or possibly a different one.

Comment: At that link, "independent of $T_1$" "means" "independent of $n$". This happens because $f$ is $T_1$-periodic.

Comment: The case with the same period is trivial. The solution at *loc. cit.* stops in fact when the period is "the same".